# Specify where to save image taken with webcame Python

Tags: python-3.x, webcam-capture

So I have a Python application that accesses the built-in webcam on a laptop and takes a picture. But I'm having difficulty specifying the storage location for the picture (in this case on the desktop). The code I have so far is:

```
import cv2
import time
import getpass
import os

getUser = getpass.getuser()
save = 'C:/Users/' + getUser + "/Desktop"

camera_port = 0
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
time.sleep(0.1)
return_value, image = camera.read()
os.path.join(cv2.imwrite(save, "user.png", image))
del camera
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/RedCode/PycharmProjects/MyApps/WebcamPic.py", line 13, in <module>
    os.path.join(cv2.imwrite(save, "user.png", image))
TypeError: img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

How can I specify where to store the image when it is taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here is where you have a problem.

```
os.path.join(cv2.imwrite(save, "user.png", image))
```

You want to do this

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(save, "user.png"), image)
```

`imwrite` expects two arguments the file name and the image to be saved.

The call to `os.path.join` is building your saved file path.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Can't believe it was such a simple error